# How to dynamically add more elements to a dropdown list with vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, html

I can't use Jquery or anything else, just Vanilla Javascript.

My initial approach was to have an array in global scope storing every registered item and then using a foreach to append an `<option>` child to the `<select>`, but apparently this only creates one option and renames it

HTML

```
<label for="productList">Show Products</label>
<select name="products" id="productList">

</select>
```

JS

```
let productArray = [];
let dropdown = document.getElementById("productList");
dropdown.addEventListener("click", initializeList());

function initializeList(){
    //initializing with an example
    productArray.push("PROD1");
    productArray.push("PROD2");
    productArray.push("PROD3");

   productArray.forEach( item => {
   option = document.createElement("option");
   option.text = item;
   dropdown.appendChild(option)
   });
}
```

Unfortunately, this is not a very efficient approach since I'd have to manually create a variable every time I want to add something. I am going to create a method where you just pass an option name and it gets added to the dropdown options. It seems that even though it's a forEach, every option being added is the same. How can I avoid this?

Comment: The options are being loaded when page loads because you are calling `initializeList()` rather than passing the function name as a reference , without `()`

Comment: When you say every option being added is the same, what do you mean? The text in the rendered dropdown or something else/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you setup the `addEventListener`, you need to send the function itself, not the `return` value.

You also need to test whether the `select` list has already been created before running the `initializeList` function. That way you only initialize it once.

```js
let productArray = [];
let dropdown = document.getElementById("productList");
dropdown.addEventListener("click", initializeList); // send initializeList not initializeList()

function initializeList() {
  if (productArray.length != 0) { // Don't initialize more than once
    return;
  }
  //initializing with an example
  productArray.push("PROD1");
  productArray.push("PROD2");
  productArray.push("PROD3");

  productArray.forEach(item => {
    option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = item;
    dropdown.appendChild(option)
  });
}
```

```html
<label for="productList">Show Products</label>
<select name="products" id="productList">

</select>
```

Comment: If I pass a reference to the function, it doesn't ever do anything. If I pass the function return itself it does load the list

Comment: I misunderstood your question initially. I need to update my answer when I get home. Clicking on the drop-down will generate the options dynamically but only within the same drop-down